# Moodle installing a block error on install.xml

Tags: xml, moodle

I have a block i am trying to install into moodle, but I get this error: -

Incorrect table "training_survey" definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

Here is the xml I am using for that table, i cant see any problem with it?

```
    <TABLE NAME="training_survey" COMMENT="training_survey table retrofitted from MySQL">
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD NAME="id" TYPE="int" LENGTH="9" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="true"/>
    <FIELD NAME="name" TYPE="char" LENGTH="200" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="false"/>
    <FIELD NAME="description" TYPE="char" LENGTH="500" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="false"/>
    <FIELD NAME="survey_id" TYPE="int" LENGTH="9" NOTNULL="true" SEQUENCE="false"/>
    <FIELD NAME="plan_id" TYPE="int" LENGTH="9" NOTNULL="true" DEFAULT="-1" SEQUENCE="false"/>
  </FIELDS>
  <KEYS>
    <KEY NAME="id" TYPE="unique" FIELDS="id"/>
  </KEYS>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key should be primary rather than unique

```
<KEY NAME="primary" TYPE="primary" FIELDS="id"/>
```